# JQuery ajax captcha validation with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a comment system with captcha for validation but i'm not sure how to use jquery form submit code inside of php if statement.

so if the captcha is correct submit the form.
it is not working in php echo

My code :

PHP :

```
if($_SESSION['vercode']==$_POST['code'])
{
}
```

JQuery :

```
$('#submitform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var rat = $('input[name=rating]:checked').val();
    $('#hid').val('rat');

    var url = 'ratings.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#submitform').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know that we can use **html** in an **PHP** file and also we can use javascript or **jquery** in an html file.
And Here you want to embed a jquery codes in php file..
So,try these codes

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['vercode']==$_POST['code'])
{?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#submitform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var rat = $('input[name=rating]:checked').val();
    $('#hid').val('rat');

    var url = 'ratings.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#submitform').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});  
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    die("Wrong Code Entered");
}
?>
}
```

Comment: NO this is not what i'm asking my question is how to write jquery code inside of php if statement

Comment: @projectsab plz see my updates.. i hope it will help you  !!

Comment: @projectsab Happy to help You :)